# using build variables in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there a way to use build variables (for URLs, API keys, etc) without using preprocessor macros?
Similar to how environment variables work - define them per build/scheme and use them in code as is?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is, no.  The only way to pass conditional valuess to your code is on the command line (i.e. `-Dxxx=yyy`) or within a header file (i.e. `config.h`).